# Is it considered a bad practice to modify parameters

Tags: java

The binary search code in java is using the following code:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex,
                                   int key) {
        rangeCheck(a.length, fromIndex, toIndex);
        return binarySearch0(a, fromIndex, toIndex, key);
    }

    // Like public version, but without range checks.
    private static int binarySearch0(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex,
                                     int key) {
        int low = fromIndex;
        int high = toIndex - 1;

        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            int midVal = a[mid];

            if (midVal < key)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (midVal > key)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid; // key found
        }
        return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
    }
```

Why was it required to copy `fromIndex` to `low` and `toIndex` to `high` ?
Is it considered a good practice to keep parameter values unmodified ?

A modification could have been:

```
binarySearch0(a, fromIndex, toIndex - 1, key);
    }

    // Like public version, but without range checks.
    private static int binarySearch0(int[] a, int low, int high,


        while (low <= high) {
```

Basically I am trying to understand if it was done with some intent with some advantage or following some good practice.

Comment: `Why was it required to copy fromIndex to low and toIndex to high ?` Shouldn't you tell us? Does it make a difference if you don't do that? What makes you think it should be done in the first place?

Comment: It's really an opinion based thing, but in general methods are assumed not to modify parameters unless it is clear from the documentation that it will (ie: adding a value to a map parameter)

Comment: Yes!, this is all about personal opinion

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's `binarySearch` from the JDK. He's asking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to keep parameters unmodified, it's a good idea to declare them final.
This also improves the readability of your method.

Answer (score 1):

As all of the parameters are primitives, then it does not matter if they are modified or not to any calling method.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, especially in the case where the parameters are primitives, it's useful to copy the parameters and write methods like that to allow easier debugging - many debuggers offer functionality to 'restart' running a particular method, and if the parameters have been modified, then it would use the modified parameters instead of the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

Some people would argue that it is bad style, but it's not needed. If you want to make it clear not to modify them then make the fields final.

For long methods I would argue that it is a good idea as it makes things clearer (you may forget that something has been modified further up in a method if you come back to it later and are using it further down). For short methods it's clear what is happening anyway.

Comment: I would argue that long method should be broken up so they are simple enough that you don't need `final` This is not always possible of course.

Answer (score 0):

Do the search using recursion, so that there is no need for modifiying low and high parameters

Comment: A) this isn't his code. It's from the JDK. B) never do recursion when you don't have to; your stack is finite.

Comment: ... and the JVM doesn't optimise recursion particularly well.

Comment: Recursion is the best way to handle the repetitive code. I dont know why u guys say use it only when it it required.